# Is it possible to find the unicode string in Vim of Windows?

Tags: vim

I found some info about the grep(findstr) in Vim of Windows can't support unicode.

Just wondering if any other way to find the unicode string in Vim of Windows???

Answer (score 2):

I use the [GnuWin port of `grep`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) on Windows, and a short test shows that it is able to find UTF-8 strings in text files.

Alternatively, you can use the built-in `:vimgrep`. It is slower, because it reads every file into a Vim buffer, but you can use the full regular expression-syntax of Vim, and it leverages the `'fileencodings'` detection built into Vim.